# what can be the Mongodb query for datatable with and without search string

Tags: node.js, mongodb, datatables, mongodb-query

I am using server side datatables with an ajax request with a search field.
I'm trying to use aggregate to get the results but i'm not getting the results correctly.

I have table in database with multiple collections and each collection have nested JSON in my collection

(Just for schema overview)

```
{
user: userId,
emails: [{
          data: value,
          data: value,
          data: value,
          data: [{object},{object}]
        }]
}
```

the above JSON have a userID and emails array of objects which further have one field with another array of objects.

**What i want**

**First** i want to select a document that matches with *user* then i want to get the length of the *emails* array for totalcount 
**second** if there is a search string in request then match (mongodb $regex) that string with some keys (data is given below ) then return all the matched data and also the count of all matched data 
so the query results the following

```
var data = {
  "draw": req.body.draw,
  "recordsFiltered": recordsFiltered,
  "recordsTotal": recordsTotal,
  "data": results
}
```

[The actual JSON is here for you](https://www.npoint.io/docs/2c2560f02310a04a6bef)

query which i tried is following

```
var Object_id = req.user._id.toString();
var searchStr = req.body.search.value.toString();
if(req.body.search.value){
    var regex = new RegExp(req.body.search.value.toString())
        searchStr = {user: Object_id, $or: [{'created_on': regex},
        {'server_on': regex },{'sender_name': regex },
        {'email_subject': regex },{'send_to_list.email': regex }]};
      searchStr = {user: Object_id, 'server_on': searchStrVal};
    } else
{ 
searchStr = {user: Object_id}; 
}

db.collection.aggregate([{$match: searchStr}, 
{$project: {count: {$size: '$emails'}}}

]).then(data =>{
  console.log(data);

  }).catch( err => {
    console.log(err);
  })
```

This is not a full query i don't know what it would be but when i pass userID only i get the length of emails array but that's not enough

i want length of emails array, filtered data (if search string else all) and the count of  filtered data to return;

Thanks in advance please check the actual JSON on the given link above

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
var Object_id = req.user._id.toString();
 var searchStr = req.body.search.value.toString();
 let query=[];
if(req.body.search.value){
  query = [{
  "created_on": {
    "$regex": "^" + searchStr,
    "$options": "-i"
  }
}, {
  "server_on": {
    "$regex": "^" + searchStr,
    "$options": "-i"
  }
}, {
  "sender_name": {
    "$regex": "^" + searchStr,
    "$options": "-i"
  }
}, {
  "email_subject": {
    "$regex": "^" + searchStr,
    "$options": "-i"
  },{
  "send_to_list.email": {
    "$regex": "^" + searchStr,
    "$options": "-i"
  }
}]
}

db.collection.find({
    "$and": [{
    "$or": query
  },{
   user: Object_id
  }     
]
}).exec(function(err, result) {
if (err) {
  return res.send(err);
}
 db.collection.find({user: Object_id}).count().exec(function(err, count) {
     res.json({matched_objects:result,totalCount:count});
})
})
```